# How to simulate country change at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

In `IOS simulator` one can set the `simulate location` among the Apple pre-defined locations or add `GPX` file to Workspace to get all the countries(with lat and long).

If we set the location while the simulator starts and change the location at runtime will it affect the simulator or not?? or is there a way to change simulator's location at runtime so that location manager can handle the changes being made?

i'm using  `CLLocationManager's` `significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable` method to track country change but simulator doesn't recognizing the change action being made.

Edit : Environment - Xcode 7.0.1 , ios9

Comment: Yes, you can change location in simulator, and location manager respond to this new location

Comment: location change is not being detected at run time.

Comment: Try making a gpx file with a route (multiple waypoints) that go across the border